# Dependency Property and callback

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a property defined as a dependency property this way:

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty HandleProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Handle", typeof(Int32?), typeof(SearchTextBox), new PropertyMetadata(HandleChangedHandler));
    public Int32? Handle
    {
        get { return (Int32?)GetValue(HandleProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(HandleProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public static void HandleChangedHandler(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var self = (SearchTextBox) sender;
        self.FindByHandle((Int32)e.NewValue);        
    }
```

With this code, the line

```
SetValue(HandleProperty, value);
```

is never executed, but the Handle property is changed.

Where this property has its value set?

Why not simply use the property setter to do this ?

Comment: `Why not simply use the property "set" to do this ?` - This part is not clear. Can you please elaborate.

Comment: I was wondering that will be more simple if the we could use the setter instead of this callback.

Comment: You can still write code in setter. But that will be called only when you set it from code. XAML never use these and this as per XAML design.

Comment: WPF uses dependency properties *only*. You could actually go rather without the CLR property (the setter and getter) than without the dependency property. It’s just how the WPF framework works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answers to all your questions can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613563.aspx). I will quote part from it here:

> The current WPF implementation of its XAML processor is inherently
>   dependency property aware. The WPF XAML processor uses property system
>   methods for dependency properties when loading binary XAML and
>   processing attributes that are dependency properties. This effectively
>   bypasses the property wrappers. When you implement custom dependency
>   properties, you must account for this behavior and should avoid
>   placing any other code in your property wrapper other than the
>   property system methods GetValue and SetValue.

Comment: Ok, I got it. I am now using OldValue and NewValue to determine property changes.